# How to load different templates for the same component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I just want to configure my Home Component according to the role.

For example:

1. If the employe has the role = admin, then the home
   component should load the template URL which is for the admin.
2. Similarly, if the employ has the role = cashier, then the
   home component should load the template URL which is for the
   cashier.

In short, I have one component and I want to load three different templates at three different times on three different roles.

Would it be possible ?

Comment: Totally possible and there are many ways to do this. Check out routing and router outlet or ngswitch for a bit of simplicity.

Comment: can you please redirect me to the best approach

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a container component or just app component holding a router-outlet tag then have the a component for each role (since the likely have different functionality). If you want just one component then you can also just hide and show things based on a variable set from their role.

Comment: actually in my scenario i have some common functionalities  for all the roles , but some are restricted around others except admin, so in this scenario what would be better for me

Comment: someone suggested me to use ngswitchcase

Comment: Yes that was me also. I think if the majority of the functionality is the same then you should set a variable based on the role and then use ngIf and ngSwitch to show or hide parts of the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use router link and router outlets, so 
you need to import

`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

add `private router: Router,` inside your constructor in the typeScript file and then you can have your conditions

```
if(role === admin) {
  this.router.navigate(['/admin-page']);    
} else if(role === cashier) {
  this.router.navigate(['/cashier-page']);    
}
```

Also dont forget to create a router link on the app-module.ts file, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: in this case i have to use 3 typescript file(component) for my three roles. and each component have its own html file right .

Comment: but in my  scenario i have one component and i want to load three different html file on runtime based on the roles

Comment: so if you have only one component for all three then it is even more easy, in your ts file just create a new variable for the role and assign the role value to the variable. Then in your HTML file just do bunch of  <div *ngIf="role === 'admin'" >ADMIN CONTENT</div> .  <div *ngIf="role === 'cashier'" >CASHIER CONTENT</div>